# Combination of draggable / droppable / sortable doesn't rearrange elements?

Tags: jquery, draggable, droppable

I'm using jQuery draggable(), droppable() and sortable() on a list of DIV's. I want to move them around, while keeping them floating left to each other and drop them on other target.

I noticed that when using draggable() the CSS property '`position`' is changed from the default '`static`' to '`relative`'. When I drop an element to another location, I want the other elements of the list to line up under each other, without the space that the dragged element used, but this doesn't seem to happen.

I tried changing 'position' of these elements back to 'static', but this doesn't help either...

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

a jsfiddle can be found here :  http://jsfiddle.net/bTCvt/1/

I tried combining a draggable, droppable and sortable here, but I can't figure out how they work together.  What I want is to be able to drag the fields around, and being able to drop them on the pink div, but the layout should arrange itself so there are no empty (vertical) spaces and the 50% elements should appear next to each other, if possible.

Without draggable() seems more like it, but then I can't use the droppable.

Comment: Show us a sample of what you are working with, probably a sample of jsFiddle.

Comment: updated my question with a jsfiddle...

Answer (score 0):

Can you look at this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/siva_hari/prd28/).

Currently it works only if you add them in order.  But this will give you a starting point. I will update if I find a better solution.

```
$('.dropcontainer').droppable({
    drop: function (event, ui) {}});
```